# retrieve data from remote mysql database in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new in objective c. I am making a UIView based app. Now i need to insert data and retrieve data from mysql database. I am tired to find out any solid tutorial or documentation and even  i don't know that about any framework or API for mysql connection. it will better if i get any example or tutorial or any other. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should never directly connect the the MySQL server, since this wil mean that you can connect directly to the server from any IP adress.

The best way of talkin to a remote host is by using a web-service, a simple REST web-service will do fine.

You can post data to this web-service, which it can then write to the database. The same goes for reading the web-service.

Comment: Can you provide any tutorial?